# Dropzone multiple uploads returned 403 forbidden

Tags: php, laravel, apache, dropzone.js

I'm implementing multiple upload for 25 files at once using Dropzone and Laravel.
On my development server, the code runs well. 25 files, all successful.
However, on my production server, 5 files are ok. More than 5 files, there will be few returned with 403 Forbidden error.

I already configured **php.ini**

```
upload_max_filesize = 50MB
post_max_size = 50MB
```

and the tested files didn't reach 5MB actually.

There is no **LimitRequestBody** setting in **httpd.conf**.

The form is included with **@csrf**.

Where else should I look into?

After couple of days, I came across this line in apache modsec_audit.log

```
Apache-Error: [file "mod_evasive24.c"] [line 248] [level 3] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/myapp/public/api
```

That points directly to the error.
Now I need advice on how to configure mod_evasive to handle dropzone multiple upload.

Comment: I guess if it works locally then it is probably caused by server configuration. Are u using php-fpm? If u do, please check pm.max_children setting in your pool configuration. This setting limits the number of simultaneous requests that can be served.

Comment: Does dropzone upload each picture individually or are they uploaded together? Question is whether there is only one server request or multiple requests for the uploads. Maybe there is a limit for requests per time interval.

Comment: `there will be few returned with 403 Forbidden error` actually take a closer look at that error, look at your chrome devtools, network tab, look at your Laravel.log. Mimic your live-environment locally (nginx config!), but then, of course turn on debug mode.

Comment: Check permissions.

Comment: At front end, I only see 403 Forbidden. At apache error log, I have client denied by server configuration. And at Laravel log, none.
Permission is not the issue here because, part of the files are successfully uploaded. And the number are varies for each tries.

Answer (score 2):

> I think this is from Apache's `mod_evasive` module. **This module protects against DDoS attacks by limiting the number of requests a single IP address can make quickly.**

You can do two options in this

---

**Option 1**

Modify the mod_evasive configuration in your apache.

1. `DOSPageCount`: This is the number of requests for the same page.
2. `DOSSiteCount`: Requests for any object by the same client on the same listener per site interval.

   ```
   DOSPageCount 30
   DOSSiteCount 30
   ```

---

**Option 2**

Add `parallelUploads` option to the `Dropzone`

```
Dropzone.options.myDropzone = {
    parallelUploads: 5,  // According to your mod_evasive limit

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.
I configure mod_evasive like this

```
DOSPageCount 25
```

I increase DOSPageCount from 2 to 25 because I have max of 25 files for the upload.

Comment: Good job. That is actually what I was actually aiming for with my question. 
In future you should provide more information about the server for faster and more helpful answers.